# Spring Forum integration

Tags: spring, glassfish, forum

My application uses Spring Security and Spring MVC and is hosted on Glassfish 3.1.2.

I'm looking for a forum software (phpBB like) that I can integrate easily in my app.

Does anyone know some ?

I found JForum but it's a web app which needs to be installed... Maybe should I install it and copy the directory in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried jForum, and even if it seems that the project is not continuing, it fits to my application.

To get it working with Spring, I had to use **SSO** (Single sign-on) by modifying jForum config.

In the file **SystemGlobals.properties**, I had to change property `authentication.type = default` to `authentication.type = sso`.

jForum will use the remote user of the request context.

See classes below for more informations

- net.jforum.JForum
- net.jforum.ControllerUtils
- net.jforum.sso.RemoteUserSSO
- net.jforum.sso.SSOUtils

Comment: Would you mind to share the portion for supplying the credentials from the Spring web app to JForum ? Thanks